# Access data filling out a Word Documents through bookmarks

Tags: vba, ms-word, ms-access-2016

I am modifying someone's access database.  The person has a button to create a report that fills out a preprinted form on a dot matrix printer.  Now he would like to print it out on a laser printer.  I suggested creating a Word document and have Access fill it out and then he can print however many copies he needs.
The previous programmer created a really nice way to print preview and print the reports.  I want to add a button to print it to Word.
I have created a document with bookmarks.
I have added the button and have added the code as follows:

```
Private Sub Print_Test_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_Print_Test_Click

'Print customer slip for current customer.

Dim wApp As Word.Application
Dim wDoc As Word.Document
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim SelectNum As Long

'Avoid error 429, when Word isn't open.

On Error Resume Next

Err.Clear

'Set wApp object variable to running instance of Word.

Set wApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

If Err.Number <> 0 Then

'If Word isn't open, create a new instance of Word.

Set wApp = New Word.Application

End If

Set dbs = CurrentDb

If Me.OpenArgs = "FromViewContracts" Then
    Set wDoc = wApp.Documents.Open("C:\Shafer\Contract.dotx", , True)
    SelectNum = Forms![PrintDialog]![ContractNum]
    Set rs = dbs.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM PRINTContract WHERE ContNum = SelectNum")
Else
    Set wDoc = wApp.Documents.Open("C:\Shafer\Invoice.dotx", , True)
    SelectNum = Forms![PrintDialog]![InvoiceNum]
    Set rs = dbs.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM PRINTInvoice WHERE InvNum = SelectNum")
End If

        If rs.NoMatch Then
            MsgBox "Record not found."
            GoTo Exit_Print_Test_Click
        Else
            MsgBox "Customer name: " & rs!Customers.Name
        End If
  
wApp.Visible = True

        wDoc.Bookmarks("CustName").Range.Text = Nz(rs!Customers.Name, "")
        wDoc.Bookmarks("CustAddress").Range.Text = Nz(rs!Customers.Address, "")
        wDoc.Bookmarks("CustCity").Range.Text = Nz(rs!Customers.City, "")
        wDoc.Bookmarks("CustState").Range.Text = Nz(rs!Customers.State, "")
        wDoc.Bookmarks("CustZip").Range.Text = Nz(rs!Customers.Zip, "")
        wDoc.Bookmarks("Date").Range.Text = Nz(rs!Date, "")
        wDoc.Bookmarks("ContNum").Range.Text = Nz(rs!ContNum, "")
If Me.OpenArgs = "FromViewContracts" Then
        ' Contract bookmarks here
Else
        wDoc.Bookmarks("InvNum").Range.Text = Nz(rs!InvNum, "")
        wDoc.Bookmarks("SalesPerson").Range.Text = Nz(rs!Salesperson, "")
        wDoc.Bookmarks("Terms").Range.Text = Nz(rs!Terms.Name, "")
End If
    
    wApp.Visible = True
    rs.Close
    rsTable.Close
                   
    Set wDoc = Nothing
    Set wApp = Nothing
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set rsTable = Nothing
Exit Sub

Exit_Print_Test_Click:
    Exit Sub

Err_Print_Test_Click:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Exit_Print_Test_Click
    
End Sub
```

**Here is the problem**:  When this runs, all I get is "Record Not Found"
If I display the value of InvNum or ContNum I have a value, lets say 18500.  If I display the value of SelectNum, I have a value of 18500.  But I cannot get it to work.
If I change SelectNum to 18500 in the Select statement, it works.

Please help.

Comment: `Set rs = dbs.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM PRINTContract WHERE ContNum =" &  SelectNum)`

Comment: ...your posted SQL queries for the string "SelectNum" instead of the value of the variable.

Comment: Thanks Tim!!  That now works!!